# Problems with div loading css on page load or refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Our homepage has a tabbed box in the middle that will occasionally not load the css correctly. I haven't found an obvious pattern as to when it does/doesn't load, nor does it seem to happen in only one particular browser.

The site: http://library.bsc.edu/

I've been testing it in Firefox, Chrome, and IE since those are what are used on campus. The box sometimes will appear fine, then on refresh or hitting back to get to the home page it will not load and instead will show the bullets for the tabs, etc.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: There is an issue with the api you are using. Check the console. As when you visit a different page, then go back to the homepage it throws the JS error.

Also, I noticed your loading in jquery twice, both different versions. Make sure you are loading the correct one.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me... what do you mean by api and console? Is the api the design code (css) that I used for the box? I'll definitely fix the jquery...

Comment: Forget I mentioned api. But yes, it's the jquery plugin that's causing the issue. Keeps throwing an error. It looks like it could be an old plugin, try using a slightly older version of jquery something like 1.7

Comment: I tried removing one line of jquery script load and changed the leftover one to the 1.7.2 version but it still seems to be causing issues... do you think I should try to go even further back than 1.7.2?

Comment: You could try going back, can you send me the documentation to the jquery plugin you are using?

Comment: ok well I'm pulling the jquery from here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js

Comment: whoops sorry this was supposed to be continued... I'm pulling the design for the box from here: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tabview/

Comment: Try loading the jquery before the plugin: I'll add an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access your URL, and found out that it is throwing following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of null
```

and source of this error is :

```
library.bsc.edu/: line 132 / 174
```

might be very first time it is calling that insert and on refresh its parent become null.

hope this answer will help you a little

Comment: ... I've tried to find the portion of the code (on lines 132 or 174) you are referring to, but I'm not thinking that those line numbers coincide with what I'm looking at. How did you find that error? Is there a validator you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Like i said in the comments, try loading the jquery before the plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js">
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Not like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Give something like this a try - http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#tabs1-html Much more up to date and more flexible